# Spring Boot application not able to connect to backend services if left idle for few hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have deployed a spring boot application. This makes couple of calls to SOAP webservices.If I make a call after leaving the application idle for couple of hours , the backend soap service calls are failing with org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException. The application works fine if I restart and try making the same call. Has anyone faced similar issues in the past?

Comment: Do you receive any response from the server? if yes, which HTTP status? Is your backend services running with enough memory?

Comment: I see WebServiceIOException being returned when external service is called. I don't see the http status code in the logs , however I am checking to see if it can be captured. The backend service is running fine. When I restart my app , it connects to backend service and works fine.

Comment: post the stack trace and the code that is calling the server.

Comment: If you receive an exception as a response, the http status is 500. Something in your backend code probably is crashing. Did you check the Http Session timeout?